# How to replace several characters on a single string to desired characters (java)?

Tags: java, android, string, multithreading, encryption

I made my own way of encryption. now i need to get that encryption to an android app. Can somebody tell me, if you have a message (string) how to replace it's characters to desired characters.

For Example ***in my encrypt method, A=Z B=X C=Y (jst for example). So then when someone enter the text "CAB" in a Textbox the output should come as "(Y,Z,X)" and yes commas and brackets must be added by the application.***

If somebody have any idea about this, plz help. Thnq vry much. (UI is not designed yet, feel free to use UI elements)

Comment: Have you tried? It doesnt sound that hard.

Comment: @KarthikT I have no idea where to start. Im new to java and android. please help! Big thanks.

Comment: Think one piece at a time, forget UI for now, replace characters first (store the new characters in an array indexed with the old characters), brackets and comma can come later. This is basic java and android is irrelevant until you get to the UI.

Comment: @KarthikT could you give me some codings to start? (actually without brackets it's real hard to understand) thnx!

Comment: I have to say that simple "write my code for me" type questions do not get a good reception in this site. I suggest you get a simple book(or online tutorial) on Java programming and give it a go first. Getting the code to output the right answer can be a very exhilarating experience and I would not want to deny you of it.

Comment: @KarthikT I know, bt giving me the same phrase doesn't help me. if i knew where to start i wont bother asking it from online community. as i mentioned earlier. i'm novice, inexperienced in java. so if you can guide me to the start i can manage my self. plz and thnx.

Comment: I doubt if you can manage anything yourself @AACaN. By the down votes you should have figured it out yourself, that all the answers in the world wont satisfy your "novice inexperienced java programmer story"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class TranslateChar {

    /** @param args */
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Map<Character, Character> mapCharCod = new HashMap<>(36);
        final Map<Character, Character> mapCharDecod = new HashMap<>(36);
        mapCharCod.put('A', 'Z');
        mapCharCod.put('B', 'X');
        mapCharCod.put('C', 'Y');
        mapCharDecod.put('Z', 'A');
        mapCharDecod.put('X', 'B');
        mapCharDecod.put('Y', 'C');

        final String toCod = "CAB";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("{");
        for (final char c : toCod.toCharArray()) {
            sb.append(mapCharCod.get(c));
            sb.append(',');
        }
        sb.setCharAt(sb.length() - 1, '}');
        System.out.println(sb.toString());

        final String deCod = "{Y,Z,X}";
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (final char c : deCod.toCharArray()) {
            if (c == '{' || c == ',' || c == '}') {
                continue;
            }
            sb.append(mapCharDecod.get(c));
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

Output :

```
{Y,Z,X}
CAB
```

Comment: This is sweet! Same way could u show me how to decode. and is there any limitations? I mean if for example "D = ab" could that be done?

Comment: @AACaN You have *decode* in this code. If you want to work with String you have to use table like `Map<String, String mapCharCod = new HashMap<>();` and double cote : `tab.put("A","Z"); tab.put("ab","r");`, you can also use the `String.toLowerCase()` or `String.toUpperCase()` methods in the map keys